# XenServer IP Failover OVH not working

Tags: networking, debian, failover, xenserver, route

I have got problem on XenServer with IP FailOver in OVH. I did everything what is in this official tutorial http://help.ovh.co.uk/BridgeClient and IP not working. On my VM is Debian 7 64bit

I set MAC adress in XenCenter for this Network on this VM and configured network

My /etc/network/interfaces (I hide my IP now):

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 94.XX.XXX.219
netmask 255.255.255.255
broadcast 94.XX.XXX.219
post-up route add 37.YYY.YYY.254 dev eth0
post-up route add default gw 37.YYY.YYY.254
post-down route del 37.YYY.YYY.254 dev eth0
post-down route del default gw 37.YYY.YYY.254
```

When I ping 8.8.8.8 i have responde

```
root@xen-1:~# ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 94.XX.XXX.219 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 94.XX.XXX.219 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 94.XX.XXX.219 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 94.XX.XXX.219 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
From 94.XX.XXX.219 icmp_seq=5 Destination Host Unreachable
```

Have anybody any idea how to fix this?
Thanks.

Comment: What does your routing table look like?

Comment: I don't know, I don't have access to OVH routetable.

Comment: No no...`route -n`

Comment: you need to do first an arping for the failover in in ovh network.